# The validity of these two proofs (real analysis).

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, solution-verification, natural-numbers

This problem is from An Introduction to Proof through Real Analysis by D. J. Madden and J. A. Aubrey.

> Prove that for all natural numbers $n$, $n^2 \geq n$.

I propose two different proofs.

*Proof 1.* This proof is induction on $n$.

We let $n = 1$, then $n^2 = 1 \cdot 1 = 1 = n$. So the statement is true for $n = 1$.

Now we let $n = n_0$, and assume that the statement holds. So $n_0^2 \geq n_0$.

Let $n = n_0 + 1$, then we have
\begin{align}
(n_0 + 1)^2 = n_0^2 + 2n_0 + 1 &\geq n_0 + 1 \\
n_0^2 + 2n_0 &\geq n_0 \tag{cancellation of addition} \\
n_0^2 + n_0 &\geq 0 \tag{cancellation of addition}.
\end{align}
Which is true. So the statement holds for $n_0 + 1$. Hence the statement is true for all natural numbers.

*Proof 2.* We use the same information and verify that it works for $n = 1$. Now for $n > 1$, we can express $n$ as an eventual successor of $1$, which is
$$n = ((( \cdots (1 + 1)+1)+1)$$
By the definition of multiplication,

> $n = ((( \cdots (1 + 1) + 1) + 1) + 1).$

> $n \cdot m = ((( \cdots (m + m) + m) + m) + m).$

So $n^2 \equiv n \cdot n$ can be written as
\begin{align}
n \cdot n &= ((( \cdots (n + n) + n) + n) + n) \\
&=  ((( \cdots (n + ((( \cdots (1 + 1) + 1) + 1) + 1)) + n) + n) + n) \\
&= \vdots
\end{align}
which is obviously larger than $n$, because $n^2$ can be written as a successor of $n$.
Hence, we claim that for $n > 1$, $n^2 > n$.
The logical union of these two cases is $n^2 \geq n$.

Are my proofs valid? If they aren't, which parts do not make sense? Thank you.

Comment: Why is $(n_0 + 1)^2 = n_0^2 + 2n + 1$ in your inductive step?

Comment: @fwd If you are referring to the typo, I have fixed that. If you are referring to the expansion of the binomial, I thought it was going to be useful in the proof.

Comment: The first line is all you need to reach your conclusion in that inductive step. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: @fwd Sorry, I am not able to see how

Comment: In proof 1, you are writing down the inequality you want to prove, and then transform it into something that is true. While that is a good way to explore, it is not a good way to write a formal proof because the actual steps of a real proof should go from something true to the thing you want to prove. So as you have written it the steps are in the wrong order for a proof. Better is to chain it like this: $n^2 = (n_0 + 1)^2 = n_0^2 + 2n_0 + 1 \ge n_0^2 + 1 \ge n_0 + 1 = n$ where the first inequality is because $n_0\ge 0$ and the second is due to the induction hypothesis.

Comment: I agree with Jaap. Note however that if you add that in proof one, each step is an equivalent statement (i.e. add a symbol $\iff$), then it becomes correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ideas appear to be correct, but the way you have written up the proofs make them rather non-understandable, and you need to fix your presentation and logic.

In proof 1, the idea of induction is: to prove $P(n)$ for all positive integers $n$, we show $P(1)$, and then show $P(n)\implies P(n+1)$ for all $n$. You have shown $P(1)$ correctly, very nice. But your logic in showing that $P(n)\implies P(n+1)$ is faulty. In particular, $(n_0+1)^2\geq n_0+1$ is what you **need to show**, but you have started with that statement without explanation, so your proof is not correct. If you instead note that each line is an equivalent statement, that is,
$$\begin{split}&(n_0+1)^2\geq n_0+1\\\iff &n_0^2+2n_0\geq n_0\\\iff& n_0^2+n_0\geq0 \end{split}$$
and then observe the last line is true, then you will in fact have a correct proof, becuse then the chain of logical implications goes back up: starting from a true statement you deduce back the true first statement.

But realise that in your entire proof, you did not ever use the inductive hypothesis that $n_0^2\geq n_0$. So it is not even an induction proof at all. In reality your proof $1$ should be written more succintly as follows:
$$n^2\geq n\iff n^2-n\geq 0\iff n(n-1)\geq0$$ which is true since $n\geq 1$, so both $n$ and $n-1$ are $\geq 0$.

In proof 2, you might have the right idea, but writing an integer as the sum of a bunch of $1$s only obfuscates whatever you are trying to say. There is literally zero point in doing this. What you are really trying to say is that for $n\geq 2$, $$n^2=n\cdot n\geq 2n>n.$$

In conclusion, both proofs might have roughly the right idea, but the way you wrote it makes the ideas difficult if not impossible to discern. So I would say your proofs are both incorrect.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I am new to doing mathematics this way (given theorems, and proving them no matter how obvious), I did not really understand induction based on what I have read in the book, but with your explanation I get it now. 

For the second proof, the gist was actually to write $n^2$ as an eventual successor of $n$, which I guess is very specific to the book, but since you provided a valid version of my first proof, I can now accept this theorem.

Comment: @kangzhe don't worry, you'll get the hang of it soon :) everyone was once there, including myself!